# Разбиение данных на категории

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть структура данных в базе

```
product1   category2
product2   category1
product3   category1
product4   category3
....
```

Мне необходимо вывести эти данные в `select` и сгруппировать с помощью `optgroup`, чтобы по итогу было как то так

```
-category1
  --product2
  --product3

-category2
  --product1

-category3
  --product4
```

Я в целом смог сделать подобный вывод

```
                $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from product'); 
                $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

                    $current_category = null;

                    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {   
                        if ($row["p_category"] != $current_category) {
                            $current_category = $row["p_category"];
                            echo "#{$current_category}";
                        }

                        echo "<p>{$row["p_name"]} </p>";

                    }
```

Но в данном случае я не могу управлять группой,чтобы заключить ее в `<optgroup>`, так как я отдельно управляю названиями продукта и названиями категорий, а как сделать,чтобы можно было заключить отдельные группы в `<optgroup>` ?

Comment: Я что то не понял, код с виду рабочий, в чем проблема то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно сортировку добавить в запрос и дополнить условия вывода:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from product ORDER BY p_category, p_name'); 
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$current_category = null;

echo '<select>';

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
    // новая группа 
    if ($row['p_category'] !== $current_category) {
        // предыдущую группу закрыть
        if ($current_category !== null) {
            echo '</optgroup>';
        }
        $current_category = $row['p_category'];
        echo '<optgroup label="' . $current_category . '">';
    }

    echo '<option value="' . $row['p_name'] . '">' . $row['p_name'] . '/option>';

}
// предыдущую группу закрыть
if ($current_category !== null) {
    echo '</optgroup>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Если сгруппировать по категориям и воспользоваться **[GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)** для объединения продуктов для категории, то может получится что-то такое

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT `p_category`, GROUP_CONCAT(p_name) as `products` 
                    FROM `product` 
                    GROUP BY `p_category`'
        ); 
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {           
    $current_category = $row["p_category"];
    $products = explode(',', $row["products"]); // <!---- в $products будет массив продуктов
    echo "#{$current_category}";
    // здесь в цикле можно пробежаться по $products  
    foreach ($products as $p_name) {
        echo "<p>$p_name</p>";
    }
}
```

в итоге в `p_category` - будет имя категории, а в `products` - будут через запятую перечислены имена продуктов. Это перечисление можно разбить через **[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)**

Comment: Сгруппировать чтобы потом делать explode? Да и для option еще и value надо, кроме текста, группировка не очень подходит

Comment: @teran если присмотреться, тут всё есть. и тексты для option тоже..... группируем по category, а бьем по products. так что все правильно

Comment: Дак value то где будет?

Answer (score 3):

Хотел было пойти спать, но когда увидел данный вопрос (даже с имеющимися рабочими ответами) - просто не смог. От чудовищной несправедливости - как будто весь мир сговорился и решил просто игнорировать само существование чудесной константы **PDO::FETCH_GROUP**, словно созданной специально для этой задачи.

Собсно решение с применением потрясающей константы PDO::FETCH_GROUP:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT `p_category`, `p_name` FROM `product`');
echo '<select>';
foreach($STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $pcategory => $pnames) {
    echo "<optgroup label=\"$pcategory\">";
    foreach($pnames as $pname) {
        echo "<option value=\"$pname\">$pname</option>";
    }
    echo "</optgroup>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

P.S. если вдруг понадобятся какие-то другие штуки, кроме `p_name`, тогда надо будет заменить fetchStyle на `PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` - ну и соответственно изменить подстановку значения в html-строку.